# Insert newline after pattern with changing number in sed

Tags: sed, pattern-matching

I want to insert a newline after the following pattern

> lcl|NC_005966.1_gene_750

While the last number(in this case the 750) changes. The numbers are in a range of 1-3407.
How can I tell sed to keep this pattern together and not split them after the first number?

So far i found

> sed 's/lcl|NC_005966.1_gene_[[:digit:]]/&\n/g' file

But this breaks off, after the first digit.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sed 's/lcl|NC_005966.1_gene_[[:digit:]]*/&\n/g' file
```

(note the `*`)

Alternatively, you could say:

```
sed '/lcl|NC_005966.1_gene_[[:digit:]]/G' file
```

which would add a newline after the specified pattern is encountered.

Comment: Nice solution, thank you. But somehow it doesn't work on my huge file :/ The output is lcl|NC_005966.1_gene_2 (/n /n /n) 5   (though it shall be 25 in this case)

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/lcl|NC_005966\.1_gene_[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]*/&\
/g' file
```

You need to escape `.` as it's an RE metacharacter, and you need `[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]*` to represent `1-or-more digits` and you need to use `\` followed by a literal newline for portability across seds.